# Spark framework not starting server

Tags: java, spark-framework

I'm trying out the Spark framework, and the [Getting Started](http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html#getting-started) isn't working for me.  I have the dependency set up through Gradle, the code (same as step 2 in [Getting Started](http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html#getting-started)) compiles and runs without error, but the server never actually starts. My process exits with status code 0 without any output. Any ideas where to look for the problem?

If it helps, I'm running it as a Java library module in Android Studio 2.1.1 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

**Edit**: I updated Android Studio to the latest version (2.2.3), and it solved my problem.